# Android TabLayout and ViewPager get position click item

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, textview, android-adapter

Good evening my friend,

I did this tutorial http://www.journaldev.com/12958/android-tablayout-viewpager#comment-37790 and everythink was fine. 
Now i want add the function on click to listView and get the position when i click on items. Please help me.

This is the factivity_main.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.journaldev.tablayoutviewpager.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            style="@style/MyStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this is the  ViewPager in the MainActivity

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (position == 0)
        {
            fragment = new FragmentA();
        }
        else if (position == 1)
        {
            fragment = new FragmentB();
        }
        else if (position == 2)
        {
            fragment = new FragmentC();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String title = null;
        if (position == 0)
        {
            title = "Tab-1";
        }
        else if (position == 1)
        {
            title = "Tab-2";
        }
        else if (position == 2)
        {
            title = "Tab-3";
        }
        return title;
    }
}
```

this is fragment_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/list"/>
```

this is FragmentA

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {


    ListView list;


       public FragmentA() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

            list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
            ArrayList stringList= new ArrayList();

            stringList.add("Item 1A");
            stringList.add("Item 1B");
            stringList.add("Item 1C");
            stringList.add("Item 1D");
            stringList.add("Item 1E");
            stringList.add("Item 1F");

            CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(stringList,getActivity());
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            return view;
        }
    }
```

This is CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private ArrayList dataSet;
    Context mContext;

    // View lookup cache
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;

    }

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList data, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_item, data);
        this.dataSet = data;
        this.mContext = context;

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return dataSet.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.txtName.setText(getItem(position));
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

The MainActivity.java class

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private ArrayList dataSet;
    Context mContext;

    // View lookup cache
    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;

    }

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList data, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_item, data);
        this.dataSet = data;
        this.mContext = context;

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return dataSet.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

        if (convertView == null) {

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.txtName.setText(getItem(position));
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In fragment**
RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(items,this);

In **Adapter**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

String[] items;
private final OnItemClickListener listener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {

    void onItemClick(int item);

   }


public RecyclerViewAdapter(String[] items) {
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public TextItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_list_item, parent, false);
    return new TextItemViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TextItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(items[position]);
     holder.textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override public void onClick(View v) {

          listener.onItemClick(position);

    }

});

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.length;
}
```

}

and in Fragment

`

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implement RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

  ...
@Override
void onItemClick(int item){

  //perform your action
     }
}
```

}

Comment: I know but maybe the tutorial need another solution. i already did that function. Please could you check the tutorial ?

Comment: You have to add interface in adapter and then implement in fragment to get item position

Comment: Please could you help me ?

Comment: follow these links for further understanding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick?page=2&tab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully familiar with the tutorial but to obtain the position you should have something similar to this.

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    int position1 = position;}
    });
```

My TabLayout has a fragment, and this code is in my fragment along with setting up the ListView data.

Comment: I know but maybe the tutorial need another solution. i already did that function. Please could you check the tutorial ?

Comment: i think he create the listview in different way.

Comment: Does my solution work when pasted inside of the onViewCreated method in your fragment? Replace listView out of my code for your recyclerView. Should work, AdapterView from my code might need to be changed as well. Hope that works.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, create an **interface**

```
public interface ClickListener {
    void itemlistener(int position);
}
```

Secondly, put the interface to your **recycler view adapter**.

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    String[] items;
    ClickListener clicklistener;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(String[] items,Clicklistener clicklistener) {
        this.items = items;
        this.clicklistener = clicklistener;
    }

    ............
}
```

Then, use the interface function in your **view holder** with onClickListener.

```
public class TextItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    private TextView textView;


    public TextItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       clicklistener.itemlistener(getAdapterPosition());    
    }
}
```

Next, implement the interface in your **fragment**. Override the method in the interface. Then you will get the **position** from your **RecyclerView Adapter**.

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements ClickListener{

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tab_A);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(items, this);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
        public void itemlistener(int position) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "RecyclerView position is: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

That's it.

Comment: @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        clicklistener.itemlistener(getAdapterPosition());
    }
clicklistener error in view holder

Comment: Please could  i have your email ? i will send my code in order to check the error ?

Comment: cannot resolve clicklistener.itemlistener(getAdapterPosition()); in view holder

Comment: Please could you contact me by mail. I will send you my code in order to undestund: pasquale.brancale@gmail.com

Comment: you could try put any int to clicklistener.itemlistener(5) to check if it's working or not.

Comment: i tried and i get "cannot resolve symbol 'clicklistener' "

Comment: If you want you can download the project here and try yourserves http://www.journaldev.com/?wpdmact=process&did=MjA2LmhvdGxpbms=